# Как изменить переменную внуьот функции с помощью другой функции python Telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

Есть глобальная переменная

```
global getmon
getmon = False
```

Есть функция с хэндлером

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda c: c.data == 'getmoney')
def getmonn(c)
    if c.data: getmon = True
```

Есть функция в которую надо как-то передать внешнюю переменную getmon. Если getmon - True закончить цикл, если getmon - False продолжить цикл

Просто использовать глобальную переменную не получается, выдает ошибку: **UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'getmon' where it is not associated with a value
"**

Comment: Используйте  ключевое слово `global` внутри вашей функции `getmonn`, а на следующей строке работайте со значением

Comment: @Ovsenka Как я понял
`global getmon
getmon = True`
Если так то всёравно та же ошибка

Comment: Так. Ну если что-то идет не так, то стоит подумать, а для чего мы это делаем. Так вот, в чем вообще суть обращения к глобальной переменной? Уверен, что решение здесь тривиально :)